# Writing IP Addresses with a different font

Tags: fonts, macros

I'm trying to create a command to printout IP addresses on a LaTeX document with a different style. It's really simple what I want to do, but I would like to do it scalable.

I've already done this:

```
\newcommand{\ipAddress}{
    {\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont
        {}
    }
}
```

And I was expecting to call the command on the text with the IP address as the argument, like this:

```
\ipAddress{100.64.0.0/10}
```

But it isn't working.

I'm really new to LaTeX and trying to give my best on the first "template less" document that I'm writing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What does `not working` mean

Comment: The IP address 100.64.0.0/10 appears with the regular LaTeX font and not with the "pcr" font family.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command doesn't take an argument, so it effectively doesn't do anything. Try this:

```
\newcommand{\ipAddress}[1]{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont #1}}
```

LaTeX provides a `\texttt` command which will set its argument in a monospaced ("teletype") font. So you can write `\texttt{100.64.0.0/10}`.

Even better, you can use the `\let` command to make a new macro that is semantically meaningful for you, such as `\let\ipAddress\textt` and then you can write `\ipAddress{100.64.0.0/10}`.

The `\texttt` command will render the text in whatever the default teletype family is. By default this is Computer Modern Typewriter. You can change the default by changing the `\ttdefault` command to another font family, using the abbreviations from the "New Font Selection Scheme". To set the teletype default to `pcr`, you would do this:

```
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{pcr}
```

So below is what I would do if I had to use `pcr`. You could modify this example to select any teletype font in combination with any other font packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*\ttdefault{pcr}
\let\ipAddress\texttt

\begin{document}
The IP address is \ipAddress{100.64.0.0/10}.
\end{document}
```

Actually I prefer the Computer Modern Teletype, which is designed to harmonize with the rest of the family.

Comment: This worked flawlessly!

Comment: Maybe you want to mention `\texttt`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\newcommand{\ipAddress}[1]{%
    {\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont%
        #1%
    }%
}
```

You do not mention which packages/engine you are using so this is my best bet as to what the problem is.

To understand the difference consider the expansion of your macro

```
\ipAddress{100.64.0.0/10} → {\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont{}}{100.64.0.0/10}
```

as you can see the group where the font selection applies is closed before the ip is typeset.

By contrast, mine expands as

```
\ipAddress{100.64.0.0/10} → {\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont 100.64.0.0/10}
```

which should do what you want.

In general, when you create a command with `\newcommand{\macroname}[N]{DEF}` in `DEF` you can use `#1` to `#N` as placeholders for where you want the `N` arguments to be used.

As mentioned by @Andrew, if you use line breaks in `DEF` they get interpreted in the context of the macro expansion so they may mean 'there is a space here' which is not necessarily what you want. To neutralise them while keeping the lines separated in the code, you can make a comment right at the end of those lines.

Comment: You need `[1]` in the definition or LaTeX won't read the `#1` argument, right?

Comment: This does not work: Illegal parameter number in definition of \ipAddress.

Comment: Perhaps you want `%` signs in the command definition to avoid extraneous spaces?

Comment: yes guys just pressed the wrong button too early =) now it's complete and should work!

Comment: @AndrewCashner good suggestion for %